# Phonegap ChildBrowser opening an External URL via a custom iOS url

Tags: ios, cordova, custom-url

I'm currently work on a iOS/Phonegap app, I want to have it respond to a custom URL scheme, so that when a person clicks on a link in the regular browser it will open the app to a specific page, where said page is actually an external page. The app thus far essentially acts as a web browser where external (web) content is displayed in ChildBrowser.

I am 95% certain I need to use the following method in AppDelegate.

```
- (BOOL) execute:(InvokedUrlCommand*)command{}
```

And I know I need to use the following to create my command.

```
+ (InvokedUrlCommand*) newFromUrl:(NSURL*)url;
```

My problem is that I've been unable to find any examples online of doing this. I know the url passed to newFromUrl needs to be in the format of `yourscheme://<sessionKey>@<Class>.<command>/[<arguments>][?<dictionary>]` But in this case, my `[<arguments>]` would be a regular url of the form "http://www.google.com".

Can some one give a concrete real-world example?

Answer (score 0):

This is implemented in current versions of PhoneGap so that all you need to do is add you custom URL to the App-info.plist file.  Here is a sample of the XML:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.cams.myapp</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>myApp</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

You should use the Property editor to edit this file and get the format correct.

[image]